# Wit.ai get bot's response

Tags: artificial-intelligence, wit.ai

I am new to Wit.ai. I have created a story in wit.ai(hows weather in country_name?). I am using the HTTP API of wit.ai for getting the response details.

I am able to get the response(http request is: https://api.wit.ai/message?q=Hows the weather in india&access_token= < access_token > )

Though in the response, i am not getting the actual response/answer, which i have configured in the wit.ai(The weather is sunny).
Currently i am getting only entity details(intent and location).

Can someone help me to get the actual answer, which i am expecting above.

Answer (score 0):

The request is correct. I've tried the same with a simple bot and it works:
[https://api.wit.ai/message?q=My email is johnny@gmail.com&access_token=MH2HINCPLBV4XCJ54N7ZO3BYQ2VKCMHZ](https://api.wit.ai/message?q=My%20email%20is%20johnny@gmail.com&access_token=MH2HINCPLBV4XCJ54N7ZO3BYQ2VKCMHZ)

Response:

```
{
  "msg_id" : "0319c0c1-f8ae-4b47-a176-488d924782cd",
  "_text" : "My email is johnny@gmail.com",
  "entities" : {
    "email" : [ {
      "confidence" : 0.9964139698515713,
      "value" : "johnny@gmail.com"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Therefore, you're not defining the conversation correctly (watch some YouTube tutorial) but anyway, this is what I've done:

[image: Dummy example]

Additionally, you can take a look at the toy example I wrote in Python: https://github.com/salvacarrion/dumb2wit/blob/master/bots/demo.py

Comment: Are you getting the message that you have mentioned in the wit.ai(Hi {contact}! You were born on {birthday} and this is your {email}) after sending the text/message "My email is johnny@gmail.com" ?